# How to add named objects to a list when declaring the list c#

Tags: c#

I wanted to know if there is a syntax to add named objects to a list in its declaration so the end result is a list of objects that I can refer to them by name (without searching).

Here's the long way (which I know works), I have used a list of employees just to illustrate what I'm trying to do.

```
List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();

Employee Tom = new Employee(id = 001, Department = "Sales");
Employee Joan = new Employee(id = 002, Department= "HR" );
Employee Fred = new Employee(id = 003, Department= "Accounting");

Employees.Add(Tom);
Employees.Add(Joan);
Employees.Add(Fred);
```

So the above works, I have named objects in a list which I can then use.

You can also declare the Employees when you declare the list:

```
List<Employee> employees= new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee() { empID = 001, Name = "Tom", Department= "Sales"},
    new Employee() { empID = 004, Name = "Joan", Department= "HR"},
    new Employee() { empID = 003, Name = "Fred", Department= "Accounting" },
};
```

However, I have to create the Name as a string in the class, instead of the Employee object.

What I want to know is, "Is there a way to do this?"

```
List<Employee> employees= new List<Employee>()
{
    new Employee() Tom = { empID = 001,  Department= "Sales"},
    new Employee() Joan = { empID = 024, Department= "HR"},
    new Employee() Fred = { empID = 023, Department= "Accounting" },
};
```

^^Obviously, the above doesn't work, but hopefully it shows what I am trying to achieve.

Edit: thanks for the answers @Ann L and D Stanley, I think I need to elaborate further on where I'm trying to put, your example works here:

```
<script runat="server">

Employee Tom = new Employee(001, "Sales");
Employee Joan = new Employee(002, "HR");
Employee Fred = new Employee(003, "Accounting");

public List<Employee> Employees;

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{     
    Employees = new List<Employee>() { Tom, Joan, Fred };

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
</script>
```

So that my list is publicly accessible, however, it defeats my goal of having the declaration and assignment in the same place, as the below does NOT work

```
<script runat="server">

Employee Tom = new Employee(001, "Sales");
Employee Joan = new Employee(002, "HR");
Employee Fred = new Employee(003, "Accounting");

public List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>() { Tom, Joan, Fred };

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{     


    base.OnLoad(e);
}
</script>
```

On the above, I get the error "A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method or property"

Comment: No, because the names don't have any meaning since they would disappear outside the scope of the construction block. If you need to access them by name later, you should use a `Dictionary<string, Employee>`.

Comment: Annonymous Types are not strongly typed.

Comment: You could create the list after assigning your variables: `employees = new List<Employee> { Tom, Joan, Fred }`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh nothing in the example is an anonymous type.

Comment: 26 second response time has to be some kind of record, thanks

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh: Anonymous types *are* strongly typed. What did you mean in your comment?

Comment: You might want to look int using an [Indexer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx).

Comment: But do thay have names? I know the compiler name them.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh A type having a name, and it being strongly typed are two different concepts. As Jon said, anonymous types are strongly typed but are not named (at design time).

Comment: @RonBeyer - some documentations around? I would love to learn.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh good place to start: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ea38b96-921c-4218-8c28-168f33b4bf62/-what-does-strongly-typed-xxx-mean-?forum=csharplanguage https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173104.aspx

Comment: @RonBeyer - `However, doing this defeats the purpose of strong typing`.Could you please explain.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh please start another question, I don't want to hijack this one for an off-topic discussion

Comment: @MrGiggles  That's interesting.  The dilemma seems to come from the fact that you are declaring fields, not variables. And field initialization runs as a separate step when the class is initialized, and has its own rules.

Comment: @MrGiggles  Expanded my answer to include another suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for *dictionary*?

```
Dictionary<String, Employee> employees = new Dictionary<String, Employee>() {
  {"Tom", new Employee() { empID = 001,  Department= "Sales"}},
  {"Joan", new Employee() { empID = 024, Department= "HR"}},
  {"Fred", new Employee() { empID = 023, Department= "Accounting"}},
};

...

Employee sample = employees["Joan"];
```

Comment: This is decent.But I wonder Why wouldn't I make a `Employee` class instead.

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I'm not sure what you are getting at, `Employee` **is** a class.

Comment: I like this so much, I deleted my own answer :)

Comment: my eyes are gone blur

Answer (score 1):

No - you have to choose variables or initializer syntax - there's no way to declare a variable *inside* the initialization.

A *slight* compromise would be:

```
Employee Tom = new Employee(id = 001, Department = "Sales");
Employee Joan = new Employee(id = 002, Department= "HR" );
Employee Fred = new Employee(id = 003, Department= "Accounting");

List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>() {Tom, Joan, Fred};
```

Comment: Thanks, please see my edited question above with your solution

Comment: @MrGiggles So those are class members?  Class members have more restrictions on using initializers.  You _could_ make the `Employee` fields `static` but that may have unintended consequences since they would be shared across _all_ requests.  If the values don't change then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
Employee Tom = new Employee(id = 001, Department = "Sales");
Employee Joan = new Employee(id = 002, Department= "HR" );
Employee Fred = new Employee(id = 003, Department= "Accounting");

List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>() {
    Tom, Joan, Fred 
}
```

Not that different from what you wrote, but a variation you didn't list.

EDIT:  The error message you get seems pretty adamant:  a field initializer (like the `= new Employee()` part of the declarations) cannot refer to non-static fields.

So if you want to initialize a field to an expression that involves other non-static fields (like `new List<Employee> { Bob, Joan, Fred }`, you can't do it.

But you could try this, or some variant. As you wished, your declaration and your initialization would be in the same place.

```
List<Employee> Employees {
   get {
      return new List<Employees>() { Tom, Joan, Fred }
   }
}
```